# Date selection using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm building a program that extracts data from several different websites that will display all our business data on a dashboard.

I've managed to get to the point where I can extract the data I need, and have it set up to select todays data, previous week and month to date by importing datetime, and for the example of previous week the following:

```
 date = datetime.date.today()
    yesterday = (date - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)).strftime('%d')
    lastWeek = (date - datetime.timedelta(days = 7)).strftime('%d')
    today = date.strftime('%d')
```

Then just using the find element function:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text(lastWeek).click()
```

However I'm running into problems at the beginning of the month, where I can't subtract 7 as it would take me into negative numbers and wouldn't go to the previous months date as each month has different days etc.

Is there any way of getting around this?

TIA

Comment: can yo share html elements for calander ?

Comment: If there is an input to enter date I prefer to set date as text. Or you may write a method to select date in calendar: click year, month, day one after another.

Comment: There's no input unfortunately, just a calendar picker popup. So I'm figuring out the date, then selecting the element based on that. I'd like a method that figures out the date, but in the first days of the month, in order to select the week to date, I would need to figure out the day 7 days previous to the current day, which would run into the previous month.